# What is the biblical basis for giving the bread/wafer to the laity at the Eucharist but reserving the wine for the clergy?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, communion, tradition

From my research I have discovered that traditional Catholic practice forbade congregants from partaking of the cup for fear they might spill or drip the blood of Christ, and then it would be trampled underfoot, which would be sacrilegious.

Was this always the case, because there does not seem to be any suggestion that the first Christians could only partake of the bread when they came together to remember the death and resurrection of Christ Jesus.

During the Last Supper with His apostles, Jesus took two symbols associated with Passover and imbued them with fresh meaning as a way to remember His sacrifice, which saves us from spiritual death and delivers us from spiritual bondage:

> After taking the cup, he gave thanks and said, ‘Take this and divide it among you. For I tell you I will not drink again from the fruit of the vine until the kingdom of God comes.’ And he took bread, gave thanks and broke it, and gave it to them, saying, ‘This is my body given for you; do this in remembrance of me.’ In the same way, after the supper he took the cup, saying, ‘This cup is the new covenant in my blood, which is poured out for you’ (Luke 22:17–20).

See also 1 Corinthians 11:23-26.

This related question [In Western communion services, when was the origin of the practice of consistently offering only the bread to the laity?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/59612/in-western-communion-services-when-was-the-origin-of-the-practice-of-consistent) says:

> But at some point along the way, it became normal for the laity to receive only the bread; so much so that the 15th-century Council of Constance "banned" the offering of the cup to the laity (so says Wikipedia).

I was under the impression that the original official Catholic teaching is that the body and blood of the Lord cannot be separated, so anyone who takes the bread actually receives both the body and blood of the Lord.  Is that the case, or have I been misinformed?  What is the biblical basis for preventing the laity from partaking of the cup of the new covenant?

Comment: I think there tend to be issues when asking for the biblical basis of certain catholic doctrines. Surely some biblical passages exist, but the Catholic realm of theology extends to places like tradition and the magisterium.

Comment: I'm sure you are quite right, Luke, and I am aware of Catholic tradition and the magisterium.  However, I'm one of those pesky Protestants who looks for a biblical basis when it comes to theology and worship.  My intent in asking this question is a genuine desire to understand the Catholic position and to clear up any misunderstanding I may have.

Comment: Personally I'd like to turn this question around--What is the biblical basis for laity needing to receive communion *at all*, let alone under both species? It wasn't that long ago that the congregation received communion *after* mass rather than during. It's not an integral part of the Mass per se, but only the communion of the priest is.

Comment: "It wasn't that long ago that the congregation received communion after mass rather than during" When was this?

Comment: @SupportiveDante - Personally, I'd prefer you to leave my question alone, but why don't you ask your own question on the biblical basis for laity needing to receive communion at all?

Comment: It's extremely rare for the Catholic Church to not see any Biblical support for their doctrines, even if the primary source is tradition or something else. So there's no problem with Biblical Basis questions for the Catholic Church. Answers just need to explain whatever support there is, even if it is secondary.

Comment: Eastern Orthodox receive both wine and bread (leavened) during communion.

Comment: @guest37 - Interesting.  I wonder why this doesn't seem to be the case within the Roman Catholic Church...

Comment: A am converted ex-Catholic.  I remember drinking from chalice of wine being optional in the mid-70s at parochial school.

Comment: @SolaGratia https://www.ewtn.com/catholicism/library/distribution-of-communion-through-the-ages-4815

Comment: This seems to be talking about medival extraordinary circumstances, such as large influxes of people. It was by no means the norm, if you read the Apostolic, Early or Late Fathers, so it seems like a burst in a unique period in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a more historically detailed explanation, see my post.

[Why does only the priest receive Communion under both kinds at a Catholic Mass?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/13834/why-does-only-the-priest-receive-communion-under-both-kinds-at-a-catholic-mass/89200#89200)

In short, the common explanation that the laity should only receive the wafer, but not the wine, is fear of spillage.  But the real reason is one of consecration.  Only the priests could touch consecrated items, like the chalice.  There was no way for the who might be the unclean laity to sip the wine.

But what is the Biblical Basis for this practice?

The Bible speaks about consecration of various objects under the Mosaic Law.

For example, the Aaronic Priests were consecrated, their clothes, the offerings, the Tabernacle, and many other items.

What of the New?  Good question.  There is a sense of the profane and the holy.  Perhaps this could lead to a plausible answer.

Comment: Thank you for that link to your fulsome answer to that related question.  I'm going to read it after I get back from church this morning.

Answer (score 0):

The laity is not prevented from receiving Communion in both forms. In fact, when the congregation is small, say two dozen people, many celebrants administer Communion in both forms. For this, the celebrant holds the chalice along with a small plate containing just enough number of hosts, with the left hand and after dipping each host in the chalice, places in on the tongue (not on the palms) of the recipient. This practice is in vogue in convents where a limited number of Sisters attend the Holy Mass.

Comment: Is this the case within the Roman Catholic Church or the Eastern Orthodox Church, or both?

Comment: It sure happens in Roman Catholic Church, and I am not sure of the practice in E.O.C.